# All module imports fail - using python and raspberry pi

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi

I correctly installed firebase and sense hat modules but at import on top of my script py script everything returns errors.

Someone who knows what the problem might be?

Sense hat used to work a few months ago ...

This is my code

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import firebase_admin
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_char_generator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sense_hat import SenseHat
```

Comment: What is your system configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

test that:

```
python3.7 -m pip install -U sense_hat --user
```

Comment: Replace Python3.7 with whatever version of Python you have installed.